# Using Haskell with Bazel

Tags: haskell, bazel

**Windows 10 (x64)**

I want to use Haskell with Bazel (2.0.0). I did on my Windows 10 (x64) machine the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweag/rules_haskell/
cd rules_haskell
cd tutorial
bazel build //...
```

Which results in the following output:

```
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64' which is a _ghc_bindist (rule definition at C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl:289:16):
 - C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl:409:5
 - C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl:445:9
 - C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/toolchain.bzl:320:5
 - D:/dev/rules_haskell/tutorial/WORKSPACE:22:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 194
                _find_python(ctx)
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 461, in _find_python
                repository_ctx.execute(<1 more arguments>)
Argument 0 of execute is neither a path nor a string.
ERROR: D:/dev/rules_haskell/tutorial/lib/BUILD.bazel:6:1: //lib:booleans depends on @rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64//:toolchain-impl in repository @rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64 which failed to fetch. no such package '@rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 194
                _find_python(ctx)
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 461, in _find_python
                repository_ctx.execute(<1 more arguments>)
Argument 0 of execute is neither a path nor a string.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//lib:booleans' failed; build aborted: no such package '@rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 194
                _find_python(ctx)
        File "C:/users/verte/_bazel_verte/idi6e53f/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_bindist.bzl", line 461, in _find_python
                repository_ctx.execute(<1 more arguments>)
Argument 0 of execute is neither a path nor a string.
INFO: Elapsed time: 11.900s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (27 packages loaded, 44 targets configured)
```

I have installed `msys2` and `python3` (Vesion 3.7.6) as descriped [here](https://github.com/tweag/rules_haskell/blob/master/docs/haskell.rst).

It seems that the error occurs in in `_find_python`. My path variable (`$Env:Path`) contains the path of `python.exe`.

Is anyone successful with building the tutorial on Windows 10?

It seems that [this](https://github.com/tweag/rules_haskell/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) azure-pipeline can build Haskell rules on Windows:

It seems that there are two steps needed to get this working:

Step 1 (Powershell):

```
Write-Host "Enable long path behavior"
# See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -Value 1 displayName: "Enable da long paths"
```

Step 2 (bash):

```
# Remove 'C:\Program Files ' (ending on space) from PATH.
# See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/10481
export PATH="$(sed 's,:/c/Program Files $,,' <<<"$PATH")"
echo "PATH='$PATH'"
```

I do not know how this can be reproduced on a (local) Windows 10 machine

**Ubuntu 18.04**

```
git clone https://github.com/tweag/rules_haskell/
cd rules_haskell
cd tutorial
bazel build //...
```

Which results in the following output:

```
INFO: Analyzed 3 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 3 targets...
ERROR: /home/newton/dev/rules_haskell/tutorial/lib/BUILD.bazel:6:1: HaskellLinkDynamicLibrary lib/libHSlibZSbooleans-ghc8.6.5.so failed (Exit 1) ghc_wrapper failed: error executing command bazel-out/host/bin/external/rules_haskell/haskell/ghc_wrapper bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/lib/compile_flags_booleans_HaskellLinkDynamicLibrary ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`cc_wrapper-python' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.554s, Critical Path: 0.37s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Building the tutorial using Ubuntu (Bazel version 2.0.0) instead of Windows does also not work for me. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for Ubuntu 18.04**

The build problems on Ubuntu were solved by installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libffi-dev libgmp-dev libtinfo5 libtinfo-dev python python3
```

**Windows 10 x64**

There is a problem when you have installed Visual Studio 2019. By overriding `cc_toolchain` it can be fixed:

```
bazel run --crosstool_top=@rules_haskell_ghc_windows_amd64//:cc_toolchain //:HelloHaskell
```